# Messages rendered halfway off screen?

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using the JSQ messages view controller as the detail portion of a master/detail configuration.  When I rotate my iPad, the right side of the messages are rendered off the screen.  When I call reloadData() the issue goes away.

Is this a known issue?  Is it due to something I'm doing incorrectly or should I just call reloadData() and ignore the issue?

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found an existing issue for this in the bug tracker.  There is a solution attached to the issue, but the issue is still open.

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1042

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a known issue but also I don't think this is a very common use case for most users. I don't think I have ever tested or attempted to run this in a master/detail configuration. The only other thing that I would think to try would be setting a `contentInset` but truthfully if you have found a solution I wouldn't worry about it too much. I do wonder tho if you rotate your iPad what happens then?

Thanks for sharing and if you find any other more permeant solutions the project is always open for more contributors.

Comment: I see this when rotating the iPad.  I guess I need to find a hook that I can use to call reloadData() when the rotate is complete.

Comment: ya you can add an observer on that it would definitely help.

Comment: Adding an observer and calling invalidate() or setNeedsLayout() didn't work.  I also tried calling reloadData(), but that didn't work either.  Looking through the layout code quickly, I didn't see where the x position was being set.  Any pointers on what I should be looking at in the JSQ layout code?  When I have time I am planning to look more closely at the insets.